# installing ubuntu to replace win7 home premium 64 x86 on amd athlon 2 (asrock motherboard) 3.3ghz 4gb ram and graphics card

Tags: boot, windows-7, usb-drive

The boot menu only lets me change the version of windows, no mention of booting from the usb.

I have burned an ubuntu iso onto the flash drive using etcher.
pressing F2 to get to the bios as outlined in the motherboard's manual only gets me to the boot screen which has no options for booting from the flash drive.

How do I get the computer to boot from the flash drive so I can replace windows with ubuntu - I still haven't seen that menu screen?

Do I need to uninstall windows first? if so I have no idea how to do that, usually you have to put in a new cd to wipe the old installation.

Comment: Change the boot order in your `BIOS` to usb first, which you can reach when start your computer. Change it to USB, then boot and it will boot first.

Comment: I can't get to the bios screen, manual says F2 but that doesn't get me to a bios screen, just a boot menu.

Comment: One moment let me see. OK try `F12` and the timing is crucial.

Comment: Any luck yet with the boot order change?

Comment: this is the only screen that comes up: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hai2if1d17y1v22/AACDW-_TMKt1EHbmrzar98GQa?dl=0

Comment: I got it F2 repeatedly after escaping out of the boot screen and it finally worked! now I just need to change the bios.

Comment: Great please place usb as first then shut down, after insert the usb then boot up and let see what happens.

Comment: Yea I changed the bios and now it's installing. Was simple after all that fuss.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, any issues always drop by and do have a nice day.

Comment: Just added an answer please kindly accept it, click check mark to the right of the answer, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the boot order in the `BIOS`. Gain access to the `BIOS` using the <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> as the case may be for your system.

Then make `usb` the first device to boot. Plug in the usb and boot again.